# Asymptotic Normality of Linear Form of Asymptotic Normal Components

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Suppose $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ are such that $A_{n}\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}A$ and $B_{n}\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}B$ where $A\sim N(\mu_{A},\sigma^2_{A})$ and $B\sim N(\mu_{B},\sigma^2_{B})$ respectively, where $\sigma^2_{A}>0$ and $\sigma^2_{B}>0$. Suppose further $$ Cov(A_{n},B_{n})\rightarrow 
c$$where $c> -(\sigma^2_{A}+\sigma^2_{B})/2$. Is it sufficient to conclude $$C_{n}=A_{n}+B_{n}\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} C$$ where $C\sim N(\mu_{C},\sigma^2_{C})$
where $\mu_{C}=\mu_{A}+\mu_{B}$ and $\sigma^2_{C}=\sigma^2_{A}+2c+\sigma^2_{B}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you need is that $(A_n, B_n)\overset{d}{\to} D$ jointly, where
$D$ has a bivariate normal distribution (with the appropriate parameters). Otherwise, the sum of two normals need not be normal.